# Excel - Any smart way to take the first line in each cell and move it to the last line?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a few sheets that I need to move the first line of each cell to the last line. For example this is one cell:

```
Chris / Mike / Ralph
Henry / Steve
Mark / Bob
```

Would become

```
Henry / Steve
Mark / Bob
Chris / Mike / Ralph
```

I was thinking of using regex but I don't see any easy way to deal with this. Copy pasting the cells to a text editor then copying them back results in the paste being in wrong as alot of cells are merged. Maybe theres a code/formula to do this but I'm not certain on how to do it.

Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: Hi, do you know `vba`?

Comment: Hello, yes I figured this out with some VBA actually. I don't use Excel often so didn't realize it was a thing and quickly made one. It looks pretty VB6ish but it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make a simple VBA script to do this:

```
Sub swap()
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range

    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
       Dim lines() As String
       Dim firstLine As String

       lines = Split(cel.Value, vbLf)
       If UBound(lines) > 0 Then
        firstLine = lines(0)
        lines(0) = lines(UBound(lines))
        lines(UBound(lines)) = firstLine
        cel.Value = Join(lines, vbLf)
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

what you can do is to add an auxliary column and the delete it:

```
+----------------------+
|         NAMES        |
+----------------------+
| Chris / Mike / Ralph |
+----------------------+
| Henry / Steve        |
+----------------------+
| Mark / Bob           |
+----------------------+
```

To this

```
+----------------------+------------------+
|         NAMES        |     AUX          |
+----------------------+------------------+
| Chris / Mike / Ralph | =count(@[NAMES]) |    
+----------------------+------------------+
| Henry / Steve        |     1            |
+----------------------+------------------+
| Mark / Bob           |     2            |
+----------------------+------------------+
```

Then order by column `AUX` and done. I used the `=count()` formula so you can have the first line as the max number `n`, then the other lines start from 1 to `n-1`. Then delete the column.

```
+----------------------+------------------+
|         NAMES        |     AUX          |
+----------------------+------------------+
| Henry / Steve        |     1            |
+----------------------+------------------+
| Mark / Bob           |     2            |
+----------------------+------------------+
| Chris / Mike / Ralph | =count(@[NAMES]) |
+----------------------+------------------+
```

And then

```
+----------------------+
|         NAMES        |  
+----------------------+
| Henry / Steve        |  
+----------------------+
| Mark / Bob           | 
+----------------------+
| Chris / Mike / Ralph |
+----------------------+
```

Cheers.